# Angular 2 AOT function error

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, ionic2, angular2-aot

When I try to deploy my Ionic 2 application to my android device I get the following error:

> Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function
>   calls are not supported. Consider 
>               replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol reducers in 
>               /Users/ibnclaudius/Development/egglr/egglr-mobile/.tmp/reducers/index.ts,
>   resolving symbol AppModule in 
>               /Users/ibnclaudius/Development/egglr/egglr-mobile/.tmp/app/app.module.ts,
>   resolving symbol AppModule in 
>               /Users/ibnclaudius/Development/egglr/egglr-mobile/.tmp/app/app.module.ts

index.ts (the part of the code that is giving error)

```
import { compose } from '@ngrx/core/compose';

export const reducers = compose(storeLogger(), combineReducers)({
  events: fromEvents.eventsReducer,
  subscriptions: fromSubscriptions.subscriptionsReducer
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
import { compose } from '@ngrx/core/compose';

export interface IReducerDef {
    put: string;
    definition: string;
    here: string;
    // or use whatever definition is result of the compose function
}

export function composeFunction(): IReducerDef {
    return new compose(storeLogger(), combineReducers)({
        events: fromEvents.eventsReducer,
        subscriptions: fromSubscriptions.subscriptionsReducer
    });
}

export const reducers: IReducerDef = composeFunction();
```

Comment: Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol composeFunction

Comment: Just a hunch, try the code now.  I added "new" in the "return new compose(storeLogger(), combineReducers)" etc

Comment: and where are you getting storeLogger() from?

Comment: Error: Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword and `import { storeLogger } from 'ngrx-store-logger';`